# ListGrid with auto size - missing columns

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm using smartgwt **ListGrid**. The problem appears when it's **empty**, and if i manually set columns width, i can get some columns **clipped** in the view port and there is **no horizontal scrolling** so **I can't access** them.

But if I add an empty record, the scrollbar appears. I've fixed it by adding

```
setAutoFitData(Autofit.HORIZONTAL);
setAutoFitMaxColumns(3000);
setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
```

But I need to add some **freezed columns** to my listGrid. I'd like to use **setFrozen(true)** method, but its **not compatible** with setAutoFitData(Autofit.HORIZONTAL);

**What I need is** 
to show a scrollbar if columns are out of the view port, even when list grid is empty.
some first columns must be frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works with the base List Grid with no additional options. But when i set

```
setShowEmptyMessage(false);
```

my scrollbar disappears.

Kind of workaround i've found:

```
setShowEmptyMessage(true);
setEmptyMessage(" ");
```